Getting out of looping (recursion)
When creating a division, the method does not find a director, it creates one, but then tries to create a division again, and so on in a circle. How can I get out of this recursion?
Only these 3 methods are looped, and yes, I understand that they call each other. How can I avoid looping?
static public Employee GetOrCreateEmployee()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the full name of the teacher:");
            string employeeName = Console.ReadLine();
            Employee employee = DB.employees.FirstOrDefault(e => $"{e.Name} {e.Surname} {e.Patronymic}".ToLower() == employeeName.ToLower());
            if (employee == null)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Enter the employee's name:");
                string name = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter the employee's last name:");
                string surname = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter the employee's middle name:");
                string patronymic = Console.ReadLine();

                Position position = GetOrCreatePosition();
                employee = new Employee(name, surname, patronymic, position);
                DB.employees.Add(employee);
            }
            return employee;
        }

        static public Position GetOrCreatePosition()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the title of the position:");
            string jobTitleName = Console.ReadLine();

            Position position = DB.positions.FirstOrDefault(j => j.Title.ToLower() == jobTitleName.ToLower());
            if (position == null)
            {
                position = DB.positions.FirstOrDefault(j => j.Title.ToLower() == jobTitleName.ToLower());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the title of the position:");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the salary of the position:");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int salary);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the department:");
            string subdivisionName = Console.ReadLine();
            Division division = DB.divisions.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name.ToLower() == subdivisionName.ToLower());
            if (division == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The division was not found. Create it");
                GetOrCreateDivision();
            }
            division = DB.divisions.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name.ToLower() == subdivisionName.ToLower());
            Position speciality = new Position(name, salary, division);
            DB.positions.Add(speciality);
            Console.WriteLine("The position has been successfully created.");

            return position;
        }


        static public void GetOrCreateDivision()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the department:");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the last name, first name and patronymic of the director:");
            string directorFullName = Console.ReadLine();
            Employee director = DB.employees.FirstOrDefault(e => $"{e.Name} {e.Surname} {e.Patronymic}" == directorFullName);
            if (director == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The director has not been found. Create it.");
                GetOrCreateEmployee();
                director = DB.employees.Last();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the organization:");
            string organizationName = Console.ReadLine();
            Organisation organization = DB.organisations.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name.ToLower() == organizationName.ToLower());
            if (organization == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The organization was not found. Create it");
                GetOrCreateOrganization();
            }
            organization = DB.organisations.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name.ToLower() == organizationName.ToLower());
            Division subdivision = new Division(name, director, organization);
            DB.divisions.Add(subdivision);
            Console.WriteLine("The division has been successfully created.");
        }

I tried to do it through flags and method overloading, but nothing worked:(

You could db.SaveChanges(); after creating the record.
This would mean that the next you query the db the record exists.
Ideally the whole create operation would be in a transaction but your design means it's not really possible as the questionnaire can take a long time.
Another approach would be to store the the created records:
Employee employee = DB.employees.FirstOrDefault(...);
         
if (employee == null)
{
  employee = addedEmployees.FirstOrDefault(...);
  if(employee != null) return employee;

  employee = new Employee(name, surname, patronymic, position);
  DB.employees.Add(employee);
  addedEmployees.Add(employee);
}

It would be a good idea to add an id to your records. Your code at the moment cannot deal with two different people with the same name.
